# Linker error when testing GitHub Actions locally using act: undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'

Tags: cmake, github-actions, zlib

I am trying to test a GitHub Actions workflow locally using act, but I'm encountering a linker error related to zlib when building my CMake project. The error message is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so: undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

This error seems to be related to the linking process and the zlib library. I've already tried specifying -lz in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Here's the relevant section of my GitHub Actions workflow (main.yml):

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y rapidjson-dev libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev python3 python3-dev zlib1g-dev zlib1g cmake
```

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing in my setup or if there's a different approach I should take to resolve this linker error when testing GitHub Actions locally using act. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Here's a snippet of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lz")

...

target_link_libraries(myproject PUBLIC z)
```

Despite this modification, the issue persists. I'm not sure why the linker is unable to link to libz.

Comment: "undefined reference" error applied to the **already existed shared** library looks weird: a shared library by itself should contain references to all other libraries which are needed. Whether `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so` library **actually** defines `inflateEnd` symbol? (this could be checked with `nm` utility). Whether `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so` library **actually** has reference to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so`? (this could be checked with `ldd`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I checked, libcurl does depend on libz, and libz does define inflateEnd, also I forgot to mention but on an Ubuntu 18.04 docker and my local Debian 11 it compiles, but when I apt remove zlib1g-dev it does not

Comment: `but when I apt remove zlib1g-dev it does not` @RLovas - why do you remove it then?

`-dev` packages, are development packages (e.g. they have .a and .so files) which are needed for compilation.

Comment: @ravenwing My apologies I didn't say that clearly.
I tested 3 environments, each one had zlib1g-dev installed. My Debian and Ubuntu 18.04 environments had no problem compiling.
I can get the same problem to occur in these two environments by removing the package. This statement is not very relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved it by using `container` to use a custom docker instance where it compiled(in my instance ubuntu:18.04), and after some hiccups I settled on the following.

```
if(ZLIB_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "ZLIB_LIBRARIES: ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}")
    target_link_libraries(myproject PUBLIC ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "ZLIB not found. Please make sure zlib is installed.")
endif()
```